# IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://securetoken.google.com/{my_projectid}/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Tags: c#, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, .net-7.0

I have a strange issue that sometime I got the error IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: **[https://securetoken.google.com/{my_projectid}/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://securetoken.google.com/%7Bmy_projectid%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration)**. I have to restart my computer for it to work again.

The problem mostly happen when I add or make change to controller or when I rebuid failed in Visual Studio.

I can access the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint in the browser. I don't know what causing the issue.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.Authority = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Firebase:ValidIssuer"];
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Firebase:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Firebase:ValidAudience"]
    };
});
```

[IDX20803 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S19P4.png)

So far restart my computer does fix the problem. But the issue still happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know what is causing the issue, but running it as WSL or Docker in Visual Studio fixed the issue for me.